# searching the database objects

Tags: database, search, object

How can I search SQL server database to find string in any of objects name? I have a problem when testers says this and that is not working and I can not find it by it's name.

Answer (score 0):

Redgate offers a tool that enables you to do this: [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=sqlsearch&gclid=CIfu5Kiu77ECFQY5nAodXGoAGw).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for objects, then you can use:

```
select *
from sys.objects so
where so.name like '%whatever%'
```